# Static and dynamic types in Java

Tags: java, types

I have a question about compile-time type (static) and run-time type (dynamic) types. As far as I understood it if the subclass overrides some method of superclass then while calling something like Parent pTom = tom, the pTom's method that was overridden must not be used and instead the one that overrides it must be instantiated.

```
public class Parent {
    int x = 0;
    static void f() {
        System.out.println("Ahem");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    int x = 5;
    static void f() {
        System.out.println("No way!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child tom = new Child();
        System.out.println(tom.x); //output is No way!
        Parent pTom = tom;
        pTom.f();
        System.out.println(pTom.x); //output is Ahem
   }
}
```

Can you help me to clarify my understanding?

Comment: static methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: A static method is global to all instances of that type.  There are plenty of online discussions and all state the same as pointed out by Eran.